# Remove all duplicated integers in list

Tags: groovy

Given the list `[1,2,2,3,5,5,6]`

I want to totally remove the duplicated values, and get: `[1,3,6]`

I'm looking for a one-line solution with less than n^2 complexity and groovy functions if possible!

Current Code I'm working with:

```
def elements = [1,2,2,3,5,5,6]

def occurrences = [:]
elements.each {
    occurrences[it] = occurrences[it] ?: 0
    occurrences[it] += 1
}

elements.findAll{ occurrences[it] == 1 }
```

Comment: If you want groovy, then why did you tag [java]?

Comment: D: Because im stupid sorry @Andronicus

Comment: PLease add a [mre] (yes that means your current code).

Comment: Done. Sorry! @Nicktar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I can currently think of is:

```
[1,2,2,3,5,5,6].countBy { it }.findAll { it.value == 1 }.keySet()
```

Or

```
[1,2,2,3,5,5,6].countBy { it }.findAll { it.value == 1 }.collect { it.key }
```

To keep the result as a list

...or...

```
[1,2,2,3,5,5,6].countBy { it }.findResults { it.value < 2 ? it.key : null }
```

Comment: I didn't know about the countBy function. Thanks tim! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
elements.countBy{it}.grep{it.value < 2}.collect{it.key}
```

This will also help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
def elements = [1,2,2,3,5,5,6]
def elementsAux = elements.collect()

elements.removeAll { elementsAux.count(it) > 1 }
```

You will get: `[1,3,6]`

Comment: That's n^2 complexity isn't it?